# Error CS0234: Имя типа или пространства имен 'Linq' отсутствует в пространстве имен 'System'

Tags: c#

Компилирую код из командной строки компилятором csc.exe.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Main() {
    }
}
```

И получаю ошибку, указанную в заголовке. Как это исправить?

Comment: А какой версии .net?

Answer (score 6):

Надо явно указать сборку. При условии, что пути к csc.exe и dll-кам добавлены в PATH:

```
csc.exe /r:System.Core.dll helloworld.cs
```

Если пути не прописаны (пример для .NET 4.0)

```
csc.exe "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /r:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Core.dll" helloworld.cs
```

Вместо helloworld.cs - имя вашего исходника.